# Cron Scheduler - every quarter end third Sunday @ 3:30 AM CST

Tags: cron

Actually I am trying to schedule an application , which has to be run at

> Cron expression to run application job for every end of quarter on 3rd Sunday at 3:30 AM CST

currently am using `0 */10 * ? * *` - which runs for every ten minutes.
when I search on online ,this link https://crontab.guru/every-quarter
`0 0 1 */3 *` this would run for every quarter I guess.

But for my requirement , which I stated above, am not sure actually.
but , i referred some of the previous questions and some trial and error , I reached something like this `30 3 15-21 */3 SUN` but am not sure. Please give your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK .. for spring scheduler cron expression, below is my best bet

**0 30 03 15-21 3,6,9,12 SUN**

should work i think. tested partially. since, the above expression will run only on june.

Comment: pls use the below link for any clarification. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html